# How to parse all XML tags and its content in between two XML tags? TBXML

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, xml-parsing, tbxml

I want to get all the child XML tags and its data in between a tag. My response xml is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GroupedData>
   <Data>
      <DataDownLoad>         
         <DownLoadMode>800</DownLoadMode>
         <Record RecordId="300000049751365" ModuleId="1">
            <ACCTTXT05>300000049822315</ACCTTXT05>
            <ACCTNAME>Amsterdam</ACCTNAME>
            <ACCTTXT02>744</ACCTTXT02>
            <ACCTTXT01>659</ACCTTXT01>
         </Record>
         <Record RecordId="300000050093669" ModuleId="31">
            <CUSTREF1>300000049751365|1</CUSTREF1>
            <CUSTKW02>INTERNAL</CUSTKW02>
            <CUSTTXT01>Subsidiary</CUSTTXT01>
            <CUSTKW01>REFERENCE</CUSTKW01>
         </Record>
         <Record RecordId="30000453" ModuleId="31">
            ...
         </Record>
     </DataDownLoad>
  </Data>
  <Data>
     <DataDownLoad>
         ....same....
     </DataDownLoad>
  </Data>
</GroupedData>
```

Here I need all the `tag names` in between `Record` tags and store it in a `dictionary`. I am using `TBXML` parser for faster parsing. I am stuck here, because tags `between` the `Record tags` are `dynamic`.

Comment: The "wiki" page for `TBXML` has example code for traversing elements, which should enable you to do what you want...  https://github.com/codebots-ltd/TBXML/wiki/TBXML

Comment: I already went through it but here, I need to get things in between the Record tags. I couldn't make that possible.